# Multiple Html Files in Single HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, reactjs

I am creating a learning dashboard using HTML, CSS, and jQuery.
I've developed a functional design, but the code is stored in a single file with over 6,000 lines.
This large file size makes it challenging to:

- Manage and maintain the code (e.g., finding specific sections, modifying components).
- Present the code effectively to others due to its complexity.

**Desired outcome:**

I want to improve the organization and readability of my code by:

- Splitting the code into smaller, more manageable files.
- Separating the HTML structure, for each section or component.
- Incorporating these separate files into your main index.html file in a similar manner as component-based frameworks like React.
  and my style.css and script.js will be the single file

How to do this in HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No. There is no direct clean way to achieve this without the use of *Javascript Framework* like *React* for example.

However, one way to do so is by using the HTML <[template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_templates_and_slots)> tag with the help of `javascript/jquery`.

You could create a components folder that contains all of your components/sections as a `javascript` files. for example (assume that we have a header component):

**components/header.js**

```
class Header extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.innerHTML = `
      <header>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>
    `;
  }
}

customElements.define('header-component', Header);
```

*Note that there are alternative ways of creating your component than creating a class but all of them require javascript code.*

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="components/header.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header-component></header-component>
    <main>This is home page</main>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have made a working [example on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-etqdu6?file=index.html).

If you want a complete walkthrough, I suggest this article on [FreeCodeCamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/reusable-html-components-how-to-reuse-a-header-and-footer-on-a-website/)

### Pros and Cons of `<template>`:

**Pros:**

- Its content is effectively inert until activated. Essentially, your markup is hidden DOM and does not render.
- Create reusable components.
- working on major browsers.

**Cons:**

- Needs JavaScript to work.
- A lot of boilerplate code and DOM manipulation to create your component.
- Unpopular with the community, thus, less support.
- There's no way to "prerender" a template, meaning you cannot preload assets, process JS, download initial CSS.

If you want to know more about it, search for [The Template Element In HTML](https://www.google.com/search?q=The%20Template%20Element%20In%20HTML&oq=The%20Template%20Element%20In%20HTML&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOTIICAEQABgWGB4yCAgCEAAYFhgeMggIAxAAGBYYHjIICAQQABgWGB4yCAgFEAAYFhgeMgoIBhAAGA8YFhgeMgYIBxBFGDzSAQgxMDM3ajBqMagCALACAA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

### Summary

As you saw working with `<template>` is not an easy and comfortable task when you have a lot of code (*6,000 lines of code as you mentioned*) so **I would not recommend it**.

If I were to work with such a task, I would go with one HTML file approach instead of `<template>` and make well-structured HTML elements where each section will be inside a `<section>` tag, well-commented and organized code, so later, I won't struggle to maintain the code.

If you persist in making multiple files I would suggest picking one of the minimal js frameworks like **Vue.js** or **React** maybe.